# Displaying subpages/subnodes in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am relatively new to Drupal so I'm sorry if this seems like a dumb question but it has me stumped, I've spent about an hour searching but I don't think I'm searching for the right thing.

I have my content setup as nodes, node/1, node/2 etc - I also have several nodes setup that I would like to be subpages of these nodes. I've set the 'parent item' to the main nodes, but what I can't figure out is how to show these sub-nodes on the main node page as a menu. In Wordpress this can be accomplished using a function to display subpages, is there a similar way in Drupal?

Answer (score 0):

Drupal core comes with a **Book** module, which is meant to structure nodes hierarchically. My guess is you are nesting links to the nodes in a menu, which works, but is less performant when dealing with hundred of nodes. To answer your question: book also provides navigation to child pages at the bottom of every parent page. See this [drupal.org handbook page](http://drupal.org/documentation/build) for an example. The list right below the content and the links below it are Book's work.